# Code splitting - main bundle has the same size with and without splitting to chunks

Tags: reactjs, webpack, lazy-loading

So I used dynamic imports with react lazy new feature. Indeed, it work as expected and creates separate chunks of js code. But this seems to be strange that my main bundle file has exactly the same size. For some reason separated code is not deducted from the main bundle I suppose. Is there a strategy to be used to lower the size of the main bundle and hence make the whole process more reasonable?

Comment: I had the same issue and then I realized when I build my app and check the output the main bundle is indeed smaller and includes all the chunks correctly. I guess the size in the chrome devtools network tab is not the actual size?

Comment: you'd have to provide more info, like your webpack configuration